# Failed to install Tor: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: tor-install

I have a problem with gpg key:

curl https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org /A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --import

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 19665  100 19665    0     0  53005      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 53005
gpg: key EE8CBC9E886DDD89: 36 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: /home/abigael/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg : trust base created
gpg: clef EE8CBC9E886DDD89 : public key « deb.torproject.org archive signing key » importée
gpg: Total amount processed : 1
gpg:               imported : 1
gpg: no key of ultimate confidence was found
```

But:

```
sudo -i
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | apt-key add -

gpg: warning : nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

Comment: Are you running the first command as a normal user and the second command as sudo? If so, try running them both as root for consistency.

Comment: I was running as a normal user. Now I did it as sudo and it works. That's great! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seen here is caused by the `gpg import` being run as an unprivileged user, and thus the key was imported into that user's keyring, while the `gpg export` was being run as `root`, and thus was looking for the key to export in `root`'s GPG keyring -- which doesn't have it, because it was never imported into `root`'s keyring in the first place.  Thus, the most expedient fix is to obtain a `root` shell (via `sudo -i`) *before* running the `curl ... | gpg import ...` command, which will import the key into `root`'s GPG keyring, and thus it can be found via the `gpg export` in the next command.

***However***, the only part of this sequence that must be run as `root` is the `apt-key add`, because allowing unprivileged users to add keys to the system's set of trusted repository keys might be a little insecure.  Thus, if operating as an unprivileged user normally, only the `apt-key` command has to run with elevated privileges via `sudo`, like so:

```
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 0):

curl https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org /A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --import

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 19665  100 19665    0     0  53005      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 53005
gpg: key EE8CBC9E886DDD89: 36 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: /home/abigael/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg : trust base created
gpg: clef EE8CBC9E886DDD89 : public key « deb.torproject.org archive signing key » importée
gpg: Total amount processed : 1
gpg:               imported : 1
gpg: no key of ultimate confidence was found
But:

sudo -i
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | apt-key add -

gpg: warning : nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found